# Not able to add data to a file Tcl using expect statement

Tags: bash, shell, centos, tcl

I am trying to create a script and that run a program and when this program is run it says either DB already running or Port is already being used by another process(Means already running)

If it is already running I wish to create a if- else statement and wish to add 1 to a file if already running but if not running add 0 to file

This is my tcl file named test

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect -f
    set f [open a2.txt w]
    cd /opt/Uni-SON/
    spawn ./Aprogram start 
    expect {
       "Port is already being used by another process"

        puts $f 1
        puts "sadsadasdsaa"
    }

    puts $f 0
```

This is my test2 file which is bash file

```
#!/bin/bash
./test
value=$(<a2.txt)
rm -rf a2.txt
if [ $value -eq 0 ]
then
        echo Not being used
else
        echo Already Being used
fi
```

ERROR :It is not adding data to the file but if I put the exact same statement `puts $f 1`outside the expect brackets it works

What is wrong ?

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this statement:

```
expect {
   "Port is already being used by another process"

    puts $f 1
    puts "sadsadasdsaa"
}
```

is that it's triggering the case where you have a set of things to wait for. You probably want to change it to:

```
expect {
    "Port is already being used by another process" {
        puts $f 1
        puts "sadsadasdsaa"
    }
}
```

Which is to say when that message is found, do the little script (two `puts` calls) associated with it. You can wait for several things at once too, and that's where `expect` becomes *very* powerful!